Allure report - steps not contains parameters -using typescript with playwright framework
Im writing in typescript, using playwright framework for our automation project/repo
we have allure report, that shows the result, video, screenshot, steps,logs,etc.
what im missing is the "parameters" inside step
i tried using allure.paramter/add paramter but it seems not to be the right approach, the parameters appear on the top of the report as group of paramters, not by step
i built @step decorator that sit on top of each method, the method gets some arguments, and im expecting to see them in the report as paramter of the function
this is the decorator
import { allure } from "allure-playwright";
import { Logger } from "../loggingUtility/loggingManager/logger";

type MyCustomArgs = NonNullable<unknown> | boolean | string | null | object;

/**
 * Decorator for adding a step to the report (html, allure, etc.)
 * @param stepName
 * @returns The replacement method.
 */
export function step(stepName: string) {
  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
  return function (originalMethod: any, context: ClassMethodDecoratorContext | ClassGetterDecoratorContext): any {
    const methodName = String(context.name);
    function replacementMethod(this: MyCustomArgs, ...args: MyCustomArgs[]) {
      if (context.kind === "method" && context.static === false) {
        return methodWrapper.call(this, ...args);
      } else {
        return genericWrapper.call(this, ...args);
      }
    }

    // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
    function methodWrapper(this: any, ...args: any[]) {
      Logger.logging.info(`Entering method '${methodName}'.`);
      return allure.step(stepName, async () => {
        return await originalMethod.call(this, ...args);
      });
    }

    // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
    function genericWrapper(this: any, ...args: any[]) {
      // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-empty-function
      allure.step(stepName, async () => {});
      return originalMethod.call(this, ...args);
    }

    return replacementMethod;
  };
}

the decorator sits on top of method -example
@step("blabla method")
async blabla(statusCodeArgs = {}):

can anyone tell what is missing ? im python developr, just started with typescript...
i have another repo in python, which there im using built in step decorator from allure-commons/_allure/step, and i have automatically the paramters in the report
def step(title):
    if callable(title):
        return StepContext(title.__name__, {})(title)
    else:
        return StepContext(title, {})

